# Angular Button Color Change with Condition

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my code, I have a list of cells, and I am displaying that list in the form of buttons. On those buttons, you can see the number of elements inside the cell. If a cell is empty, I want it the button to be green and if it has any elements in it, I want it to be red. My code is below, how can I do this?

```
 <button mat-button class="green fuse-white-fg" 
                            *ngFor="let prm of cell">Package Count: {{prm.PackageCount}}</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another way to do it as.

```
<button mat-button [class.green]="!prm.PackageCount" [class.red]="prm.PackageCount" *ngFor="let prm of cell">
  Package Count: {{prm.PackageCount}}
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ngStyle` attribute:

```
<button mat-button [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': prm.PackageCount ? 'green' : 'red' }" *ngFor="let prm of cell">
  Package Count: {{prm.PackageCount}}
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ngclass`.

```
 <button mat-button class="fuse-white-fg" 
                    [ngClass] = "{'green':!prm.PackageCount, 'red':prm.PackageCount>0}"
                    *ngFor="let prm of cell">Package Count: {{prm.PackageCount}}</button>
```

where `green` and `red` are css classes

Comment: Thanks the buttons turns red know. But, the empty ones (green ones) disappear from the screen. Should I add something else?

Comment: how is your green glass defined?

Comment: can you tell me if they disappeared from the DOM or are just a color you cannot see?

Comment: It's just the color, they haven't disappeared from the DOM

Comment: okay, I reread your question and updated my answer accordingly - you want it green if there is nothing, but that doesn't necessarily mean the count is 0